# GstCollectPads how to push data from data_collected callback function?

Tags: plugins, gstreamer

I'm trying to write a plugin which has multiple request sink pads. My plugin should process samples collected from sink pads collectively, and than pass it further. 
I'm trying to use GstCollectPads for this purpose, i've set callback for processing collected data, and i'm trying to pass this collected data to my processing algorithm which should return processed data and pass it down the pipeline.

My question is: How should I collect data from GstCollectedPads and pass it on to my algorithm, and then push output from my algorithm down to the sinkpads of my plugin?

I have already created GstCollectPads object, I have added sink pads to this object and set callback function to be called when data is collected. If someone could write some short example for using GstCCollectPads I would be very thankful, since I'm unable to figure out the proper usage from documentation.

Comment: By the way if you're looking for an example of code using collectpads, take a look at http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-good/tree/gst/videomixer/videomixer2.c

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a recent enough version of gstreamer, I encourage you to take a look at a new base class we implemented, called GstAggregator, which purpose is to replace collectpads. the videomixer and audiomixer elements have been ported to that new base class, namely as [compositor](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-bad/tree/gst/compositor/compositor.c) and [audiomixer](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-bad/tree/gst/audiomixer/gstaudiomixer.c).

If your element deals with video buffers, you might want to consider inheriting from [videoaggregator](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-bad-libs/html/gst-plugins-bad-libs-GstVideoAggregator.html), compositor is a good example of that, otherwise you can inherit directly from [aggregator](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-bad-libs/html/gst-plugins-bad-libs-GstAggregator.html) and implement the aggregate virtual method, the documentation and looking at audiomixer should be sound examples.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this, however I've got a lot of code written already,  which is why for now I prefer to stay with gstcollectpads. Thus my question is still open.

Comment: No problem, I don't want to write code involving collectpads though, there's a reason why we wrote aggregator in the first place ;)